# Uncommon elements in multiple lists

Tags: c#, linq, list, hashset

I have multiple lists and i want to find distinct uncommon elements in everylist.

I came to a point but couldnt managed to get the uncommon elements but ended up common elements.

Here is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DataTable> dataTables = new List<DataTable>();

        List<string> c = new List<string>();
        c.Add("A");
        c.Add("B");
        c.Add("C");
        dataTables.Add(ss(c));            
        c.Add("B");
        c.Add("C");
        dataTables.Add(ss(c));
        c.Add("A");
        c.Add("B");
        dataTables.Add(ss(c));


        var setsOfIds = dataTables.Select(t => t.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("ELIGIBLE")).OfType<string>());                        
        var commonIds = IntersectAll<string>(setsOfIds);
        var rows = dataTables.SelectMany(t => t.AsEnumerable()).Where(r => commonIds.Contains(r.Field<string>("ELIGIBLE")));
        var resultRows = rows.GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("TEDARIKCI")).Select(r => r.First());

    }

    private DataTable ss(List<string> aa)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("x");
        dt.Columns.Add("ELIGIBLE", typeof(string));
        DataRow dr = null;//= dt.NewRow();

        foreach (string item in aa)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = item;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        return dt;
    }

    public List<T> IntersectAll<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> lists)
    {
        HashSet<T> hashSet = null;
        foreach (var list in lists)
        {
            if (hashSet == null)
            {
                hashSet = new HashSet<T>(list);                    
            }
            else
            {
                hashSet.IntersectWith(list);
            }
        }
        return hashSet == null ? new List<T>() : hashSet.ToList();
    }
```

IntersectAll does not help me because it gives me A,B,C. But i only want B (which is common to all of each list)

I would appreciate if s.o. could give a sample. This is driving me crazy!! Pleeeeaaseeee

Comment: Could you simplify your problem, what's expected result?

Comment: Either your implementation of IntersectAll is bad, or you've really named it badly.  IntersectAll should give "B" (an intersection of all lists).  A routine that gives "A","B","C" should be named UnionAll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the first list had `3` elements (ABC), the second had `5`(ABCBC) and the third had `7` (ABCBCAB).

In other words, all the list had `A, B, C` ..

Creating `new` `List` before adding to `dataTable` would solve this issue

```
        List<DataTable> dataTables = new List<DataTable>();

        List<string> c = new List<string>();
        c.Add("A");
        c.Add("B");
        c.Add("C");
        dataTables.Add(ss(c));

        List<string> c2 = new List<string>();//New List
        c2.Add("B");
        c2.Add("C");
        dataTables.Add(ss(c2));

        List<string> c3 = new List<string>();//New List
        c3.Add("A");
        c3.Add("B");
        dataTables.Add(ss(c3));

        var setsOfIds = dataTables.Select(t => t.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("ELIGIBLE")).OfType<string>());                        
        var commonIds = IntersectAll<string>(setsOfIds);
```

Here `commonIds` list would contain only one element `B`

Comment: holy sh.t ! that is exactly the reason why one should not work more than 10 hours a day :)) thanks for figuring it out :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var l1 = new List<string> {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
var l2 = new List<string> {"B", "C", "E"};
var l3 = new List<string> {"A", "B"};

var c = l1.Intersect(l2).Intersect(l3);
```

returns "B"

```
var uc1= l1.Except(l2).Except(l3);
var uc2= l2.Except(l1).Except(l3);
var uc3= l3.Except(l1).Except(l2);
var uc=uc1.Union(uc2).Union(uc3);
```

should give:

```
uc1 = "D"
uc2 = "E"
uc3 = {empty}
uc = "D","E"
```

Comment: Hi Robert, I have tons of examples within limited number of lists. But indeed, for instance i need an extesion method to handle n numbers of lists.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you want. You seem to be asking for a method to find elements that only appear in one list (no 2 lists have them in common), but your expected results seem to suggest you want to find elements that ALL lists have in common. In any case, both are fairly easy with Linq.

This will find all elements that appear exactly once in all lists:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindUniques<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> lists)
{
    return lists.SelectMany(x => x).GroupBy(x => x)
                .Where(g => !g.Skip(1).Any())
                .Select(g => g.First());
}
```

This fill find all elements that appear in every list:

```
public IEnumerable<T> IntersectAll<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> lists)
{
    return lists.Aggregate((a, x) => a.Intersect(x));
}
```

For example:

```
var list1 = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
var list2 = new[] { "B", "C", "D" };
var list3 = new[] { "C", "D", "E" };

FindUniques(new[] { list1, list2, list3 }); // { "A", "E" }
IntersectAll(new[] { list1, list2, list3 }); // { "C" }
```